# Shared note folders not visible in icloud notes

Tags: icloud, sharing, notes.app

As soon as one shares a folder in Apple's notes app, be it in the web version or in any of the apps, the folder vanishs from the web version. So the question is: How can one view shared folders on the web?

Comment: Is there a question here? It seems clear that iCloud.com doesn't show shared folders (I've confirmed this on mine, for example) and so there wouldn't really be an answer here. There's no solution except to not have them.

Comment: The question is, of course, how to view shared folders on web?

Comment: @Ezekiel yes, there is a question. No matter what the answer is to a question, that doesn't change the validity of the question. Please don't post questions to questions, asking if a question is being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated for September 2023:

Notes on iCloud.com now supports Shared Folders. No action is needed to gain access to this new feature.

---

<strike>You cannot view Shared Folders on the iCloud.com web view.</strike>

<strike>As pointed out, it appears the notes themselves do appear, in the All iCloud area of the Notes web app.</strike>

Comment: The contents of shared folders within iCloud.com are there, but the entire directory structure becomes inaccessible and all files moved to "All iCloud" folder. In Notes.app, the directory structure and all shared files/folders remain.